# Regular Expressions for Consecutive Words

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I'm running a Apache pig script and I'd like to be able to look for a full string of words in a field. For example I would like to look for "following updates are downloaded and ready for installation"

The issue I'm having is that `matches` with RegEx only seems to allow me to enter single words to search for. So I end up looking for "following" & "updates" & "downloaded" & "ready" & "installation" and it doesn't matter how far apart they are. I've resorted to just including more words to try to lock down what I'm looking for but I wanted to see if looking for an entire string of consecutive words is possible.

Here is an example of my current filter.

```
downloadFilter = FILTER windowsLog BY ($16 matches '^(?=.*?(following))(?=.*?(updates))(?=.*?(downloaded))(?=.*?(ready))(?=.*?(installation)).*$');
```

Example record I'm trying to hit.

```
3/7/2014    19:15:54:141    972 13c0    Report  REPORT EVENT: {EF338545-61FB-434A-ACB6-F9D17A986677}    2014-03-07 19:15:49:141-0600    1   188 102 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0   AutomaticUpdates    Success Content Install Installation Ready: The following updates are downloaded and ready for installation. This computer is currently scheduled to install these updates on ‎Saturday, ‎March ‎08, ‎2014 at 3:00 AM:  - Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2836943) - Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2863240) - Update for User-Mode Driver Framework version 1.11 for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2685813) - Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2791765)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `(?=.*?Download Completed)`?

Comment: Can you give a better example of `windowsLog`, and what makes up `a full string of words`?  Can it just be sets of alphabetic characters delimited by spaces?  Or does it need to be more specific sets of words like your regex.

Comment: Post and log example, and make your question more objective, like: "I NEED THIS OUTPUT",

Comment: @Robin when I try that I get nothing back. I think Pig 'matches' doesnt parse the white space.

Comment: I've added an example record I'm trying to hit.

Comment: @dreyco676: You do know `Download Completed` is not in your example record?

Comment: @Robin, yes sorry I updated my post with a better example. The issue with having spaces in the `matches` function still seem to occur.

Comment: I appreciate the thought, but I'm afraid the string still doesn't contain `Download Completed`...

Comment: I meant the example of what I'm looking for is now "following updates are downloaded and ready for installation"

Comment: Woops, sorry about that. So just to be sure, `(?=.*following updates are downloaded and ready for installation).*` (with the `.*` at the end) didn't return anything?

Comment: Pff... That works! I **swear** I tried that before. THANKS! EDIT: I think before I was only doing `.*Terms I'm Looking for.*`

Comment: EDIT:EDIT: I'm just crazy. Both work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply search for the following `regex`:

`'.*Download Completed.*'`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/oR7aP3

Comment: Why use a capturing group here?

Comment: @Robin, You're right. It's not necessary. I'll remove it.

Comment: @Robin, There done. I just have this habit of capturing "seemingly" important stuff

Comment: Thanks this works even though I swear I tried this before I posted.